# How to compare two dates in different columns in Excel to find a row where one date is earlier than the other?

Tags: excel

I have a set of data in Excel where I have patient IDs, treatment start date, and surgery dates. I am trying to find out which patients had no treatment prior to surgery. Alternatively, the data can also be queried using SQL, but I don't know where to begin.
I know a simple IF statement isn't working, other than that, I don't know where to begin. 
`=IF(D5>E5, "no prior treatment", "not eligible")`

Comment: Post a sample of your data and the expected results

Comment: I think your **IF** function might actually work. How about give a screenshot of your sample data and what your function is returning, and if it is not working please point out the expected output.